# Как сделать так, чтобы при инициализации абсолютно позиционированный элемент был по середине вью-порта

Tags: html, css

Есть html которые генерируется динамически.
Есть body и у него realtive позиционирование.
Есть элемент, у него позиционирование абсолютное относительно body.
Но body подгружается динамически и его размер через несколько секунд становится нормальный и элемент виден нормально, но ДО того оно выглядит вот так страшно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы до того как размер body будет нормальным элемент был по середине вью порта (там где две большие стрелы) или хотя бы был виден полностью.

Чего нельзя делать, вот вообще.
Задачу нельзя решить с помощью JS, просто запрещено хоть это и делается элементарно.
body нельзя выставить min-height, тоже запрещено.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Что если положить в body абсолютный элемент с `height: 100vh;` и уже в него класть вашу центрированную штуку

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/122552)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov что тебя смущает

Comment: Либо Вы даете полный и законченный ответ, либо задаете уточняющие вопросы в **комментариях"* к вопросу

Comment: @AntonShchyrov дак что тебя не устраивает в ответе? Я описал способ решения. Мне что, обсосать надо что такое 100vh или что?